# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient,...'

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I'm having trouble using system.data.sqlclient namespace.
I have made a very simple console application to save entered data in database.
Need help regarding this, please help. I have attached screenshot of console.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace StudentDetails_Proj
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Age:");
            string age = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Id:");
            string id = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Address:");
            string address = Console.ReadLine();
            // string connectionstring = "Server=G2W9DRV2E;Database=UserLogin;User Id=sa;Password=Password1";
            string connectionstring = "Server=G2W9DRV2E;Database=UserLogin;Integrated Security=true";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            connection.Open();
            string cmdText = string.Format("Insert into StudentInfo values('{0}',{1},{2},'{3}')", name, age, id, address);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Unhandled Exception: **System.BadImageFormatException**: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)
>
> **System.BadImageFormatException**: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution

Comment: Try to install the [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) NuGet package.

Comment: If you are working in .NET Core try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439150/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlclient-version-4-2-0-2-when-i-us

Comment: If it is PCL try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34674123/2946329

Comment: Try Navigating to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects and check > Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects`


Clean up Solution and Build it and Run in Admin Mode

Comment: Integrated Security=true means you are using a windows credential so you cannot use a login.  Open Server with SQL Server Management Studio.  There is a Server/Instance in the login window.  Make sure you are using both the Server/Instance in your connection string.

Comment: Thank you !! It worked after installing System.Data.SqlClient nuget package

Comment: See my answer on **[System.BadImageFormatException: Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336306/system-badimageformatexception-reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-ex/61702386#61702386)**.