# Getting exception while executing Azure function locally when trying to connect to local database

Tags: azure-functions, .net-standard-2.0, .net-core-2.0, azure-functions-runtime

[image: Azure function error]

Have installed nuget for System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.1. Getting below error on running

[5/28/2020 4:09:39 PM] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=990d4cbf-bd32-4a77-ab52-8b5fb1dce252)
[5/28/2020 4:09:39 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Function1. FunctionAppDemo: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.6.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

Even when I downgrade to Version=4.6.1.1, I get similar error with version 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I didn't reproduce your issue on my side. I am using `.NET Core 2.0` and `System.Data.SqlClient(4.8.1)`.

[image]

Please go to **Dependencies** to check if `System.Data.SqlClient` is there.

If the dependency is there, you can refer to the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49439150/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-data-sqlclient-version-4-2-0-2-when-i-us).